# Adding wp_deregister_script('jquery'); deactivates "Quich Edit" at WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using WordPress.

I added this code to functions.php:

```
function modify_jquery() {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', false, '1.4.4');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Later I found "Quick Edit" is broken and when trying to quick edit a post it just disappear.

Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the version 1.4.4 of jQuery?
Can't you use the latest : http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js ?

I use the last one, on the action **wp_enqueue_scripts**
And it's fine for me.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'actionRegisterAssets', 0);
function actionRegisterAssets()
{
// Unregister default scripts
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js', array(), '1.7.2');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```